# How to Schedule an Event to execute every day with a Service?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, service, ftp

I made a MS Service in VB.NET and it's all set. I Also have some code to download files from FTP server and its also working. I need to Download these files every day at 1:00 AM. The service will be running on a server.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing this as a Console Application, then scheduling it to run at 1:00am via [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is typically far simpler than trying to build the scheduling into a service, and provides more flexibility, as it's simple to adjust the schedule without recompiling.

---

If you must run as a service, then you could use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) to repeat and handle your scheduling within the Service.

Comment: That definetly will work, but it has to run with a Service. Thanks!!

Comment: @EmmanuelSantana Why do you need it to run as a service?  This provides all of the benefits, simplifies the code, and has no real drawbacks...

Comment: It is a requirement but this seems to be better. This Is very Helpful

Comment: The [Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) is timer of choice for a Windows Service.

Comment: @DonA `Timers.Timer` or `Threading.Timer` both use the same timing mechanism.  Either would be fine for use in a service.